# Преобразовать изображение в массив double

Tags: java, изображения, bufferedimage

Для нейронной сети мне необходимо преобразовать изображение в массив double, значения должны быть от 0 до 255.
Я пытался это делать  так

```
 public static double[] createArrayfromImage(BufferedImage inImage) {       
        double[] arr = new double[inImage.getHeight() * inImage.getWidth()];
        int i = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < inImage.getHeight(); y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < inImage.getWidth(); x++) {
              System.out.println(inImage.getRGB(x, y));
                arr[i] =inImage.getRGB(x, y)/255;
                i++;
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Но я не получаю значения в нужном цветовом диапазоне.
Пытаюсь получить через массив байтов,но размерность байтового массива получается не такой как размерность изображения

```
public static byte[] createByteArray(BufferedImage inImage) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(inImage, "jpg", bos );
    return bos.toByteArray();
}
 double[] img = new double[28 * 28];            
        byte[] arre=Data.createByteArray(b);
        for (int d = 0; d < img.length; d++) {                
            System.out.println(arre.length);
            img[d] = (Data.createByteArray(b)[d] & 255) / 255.0;
        }
```

Что я не так делаю?

Comment: Вопрос в том, что возвращает функция getRGB() и как это "что то" автоматически конвертируется в double. Кроме того, в строке arr[i] =inImage.getRGB(x, y)/255; в знаменателе - целое число, не приводит ли это к неправильному преобразованию типа? Также, во многих случаях сетке скармливают черно - белые изображения, тогда нужно просто преобразовать цвет к черно белому.

Answer (score 0):

Во первых - `arr[i] =inImage.getRGB(x, y)/255;` здесь у вас целочисленное деление. Метод getRGB() возвращает значение типа int и вы делите его также на значение типа int. Замените целочисленный литерал 255 на литерал типа double (255.0) b почитайте про авто приведение типов в Java.

Во вторых - в каком формате вы хотите сохранить каждый пиксель и в каком формате их возвращает метод getRGB() (ARGB, RGBA ил может быть RGB)? Непонятно, что вы пытаетесь поместить в double - оттенок серого или какой один из компонентов цвета (r, g или b)? В общем - уточните вопрос.